# How to proceed with complex object in POST request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, post

Hello SO I had 2 entities

**Main entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Events")
public class Event {

//Some fields ...

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "event_eventtypes" ,
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_type_id"))
private Set<EventType> eventTypes;

//Getters and setters...
```

Now I have a form that is created using spring **form-taglib**

```
<form:form modelAttribute="event" method="post" action="/event/registerEvent" commandName="event">

<form:label path="name">Event display name</form:label>
<form:input  path="name" type="text" cssClass="form-control" placeholder="Display name"/>

<form:label path="description" >Description</form:label>
<form:textarea path="description" cssClass="form-control"/>

<form:label path="priv" cssClass="">Make private? <span style="font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:11px; color: dodgerblue;">(It will be seen by your friends and people who you send invitation.)</span></form:label>       
<form:checkbox path="priv" cssClass="form-check-input"/>

<form:label path="age">Age limit</form:label>
<form:select path="age">
  <form:options items="${age}"/>
</form:select>


<form:hidden path="lng" id="formLang" />
<form:hidden path="lat" id="formLat"/>
<%--Question appear here--%>
<form:select path="eventTypes" items="${eventTypes}" multiple="true"/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class EventController {

   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventController.class);

   @Autowired
   private EventService eventService;
   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;
   @Autowired
   private EventTypeService eventTypeService;

   @RequestMapping(path = "/event/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String init(ModelMap modelMap) {
       List<String> tags = eventTypeService.listEventTypes().stream().map(EventType::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
       ArrayList<Integer> ageArr = new ArrayList();
       ageArr.add(0);
       ageArr.add(6);
       ageArr.add(12);
       ageArr.add(16);
       ageArr.add(18);
       modelMap.addAttribute("event", new Event());
       modelMap.addAttribute("age", ageArr);
       modelMap.addAttribute("eventTypes", tags);
       return "/event/create";
   }

   @RequestMapping(path = "/event/registerEvent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String createEvent(@ModelAttribute("event") Event event, @ModelAttribute("eventTypes1") List<String> eventTypes){
       event.setDate(new Date());
       event.setUser(userService.getUserByUsername(
            AuthenticationService.getLoggedInUser())
       );
       eventService.addEvent(event);

       return "redirect:/";
   }
```

When complete form with values, click submit, get error

> 400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

It's because eventTypes property is of String type. How can I send that list as another parameter in controller or what should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found soulution.
Just implement jsp-based form as :

```
<form:form modelAttribute="event" method="post" action="/event/registerEvent" commandName="event">

     ... 

    <%--There I'm not using more jsp tabs.--%>
    <select multiple name="et" id="tags">
       <c:forEach items="${eventTypes}" var="e">
           <option value=${e}>${e}</option>
       </c:forEach>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form:form>
```

In Controller I get parameters as `request.getParameterValues("et"))` - that return `String[]` from HttpServletRequest

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a DTO to include event and eventType list both.

Answer (score 0):

When I have done this I send a DTO with a list of IDs/Strings for event types to the form and then create a new event from the DTO.

For the select statements loop round each option returned in the DTO and use a service findById to retrieve each eventType and then add this to the event model.

```
for (String tag : eventDTO.getEventTags()) {

    EventType eventTag = eventTypeService.findById(Long.valueOf(tag));

    if (eventTag != null) {
        event.getEventTypes().add(eventTag );
    }
}
```